# Change the font color of TextView when ListView Item gets selected

Tags: android, android-listview

There is a TextView in every ListView Item which I am setting through custom adapter. The TextView XML is not in same file where a ListView XML has been written, I want that when any Item of ListView gets selected the font color of that particular item should change. I also tried this by defining the different states of TextView i.e selected, focused and pressed but that dose not solve my problem. Please suggest me some solutions for it. Here is snippet..

a listeview in one xml file for eg. file1.xml

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:clickable="true" />
```

and a TextView in different xml.. i.e file2.xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rowListTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textColor="@color/file3"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

file for text color attribute in res/color folder i.e file3.xml.

```
<item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@android:color/white"/>
<item android:state_focused="true"  android:color="@android:color/white"/>
<item android:state_pressed="true"  android:color="@android:color/white"/>
<item android:color="@android:color/black"/>
```

Comment: teerapap's answer is the best answer - i think it must be accepted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below snippet will help you.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView <? > adapterView, View rowView,
    int position, long id) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowListTextView);

        textView.setTextColor("Desired Color");

    }
});
```

I have not included scenario like retaining text color when you scroll the list and your selected item goes out of focus. This snippet will guide you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks vipul I tried that and it helped somewhere as its changing font color of that particular Item where it is been clicked but now I want that it should retain the original color once the clicked is gone from that particular position. can u help me that way. Thanks.

Comment: And how to change the TextView's color without Click, for example when the ListView is created.

Answer (score 22):

Try this color state list for textColor.

```html
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#fff"/>
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:color="#fff"/>
    <item android:color="#000" />
</selector>
```

[Android guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html) does not mention `state_activated` attribute but it works for me.

Comment: `android:state_activated` is definitely what you want. Why this ish isn't documented is crazy. I spent about 30 mins trying to get this to work, then I tried this and it works.

Comment: Is this possible for image's too, I want to switch between two images, I tried instead of android:color to android:src for the image but errors me

Answer (score 14):

In selector:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
    <item  android:state_activated="true"  android:color="#ff0000" />
    <item android:state_active="true" android:color="#ff0000" />  
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#ff0000" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="#ff0000" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#ff0000" />
    <item android:color="#000000" />
</selector>
```

In activity: `myListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);`

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                      int position, long id) {
                     pl=position;
                     myListView.setItemChecked(pl, true);
                     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                          .....
```

item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="@drawable/selector"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    />
```

And my checked item in red color after i click them. Only one checked item. Enjoy!

Comment: in case of element selection in listview, this should be accepted answer. Nice answer @Master , actually.